# Is it possible to simulate Javascript-style prototypes in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, prototype

I'd like to know whether it's possible to simulate Javascript prototypes in Java. Is it possible to associate a list of variables with a function in Java? I want to create something similar to Javascript prototypes, if that's even possible.

So here's an example (in Javascript):

```
    var s = doStuff.prototype;
s.isImplemented = false;
function doStuff(){
    //this function has not yet been implemented
}

var s = functionIsImplemented.prototype;
s.isImplemented = true;
function functionIsImplemented(theFunction){
    //this function returns true if the function has been identified as "implemented"
    if(theFunction.prototype.isImplemented == true){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
alert(functionIsImplemented(doStuff)); //this should print "false"
alert(functionIsImplemented(functionIsImplemented)); //this should print "true"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Is there any way to do the equivalent of this in Java?

Comment: Functions (Methods) in Java are NOT first-class citizens. You can't pass them around or associate properties/attributes to them. They *must* always be escorted by a class. You WILL need some class/object based design to pull it off, but what is your intent? What are you trying to do and why?

Comment: I use function prototypes in Javascript to identify functions as implemented or not implemented, so that I can determine which functions can be implemented at any given time. (I now realize that it would be possible to avoid this issue altogether in Java by simply creating an array that would contain each of the function names that I'm working with.)

Comment: Also, method annotations may be useful for this purpose: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang.reflect/MethodgetAnnotationClassMyAnnoannotationClass.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible, and can be very useful for some situations.

Typically you would do the following:

- Create a class that contains a Map of properties. This becomes your "Base Object" class for all your prototypes. K is probably String, V is probably Object
- Create getters and setters for your properties
- Optionally add other utility methods, for example checking if a function is implemented basically means checking of the property map contains a specific key
- Implement prototype-based inheritance by either cloning the property map of another object or (more complex) keeping a reference back to the original object
- Use function objects of some sort to allow the storage of arbitrary code within properties

It's not as elegant as if you do this directly in a dynamic language, but it works and gets you the same benefits (runtime flexibility, avoid constraints of rigid OOP, fast proptotyping etc.).

It also has the same downsides - loss of static type checking and some performance overhead being the main ones.

As an example, the open source game I wrote ([Tyrant](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tyrant/)) uses this approach for all the in-game objects.

Comment: Can you provide some basic example usages of this (I mean source code examples)?

Comment: Have a look in the Tyrant source - e.g. https://github.com/mikera/tyrant/blob/master/src/main/java/mikera/tyrant/Potion.java contains code which generates lots of different potion types with different properties and special effects (function objects)

Comment: Method annotations may be useful for this purpose as well (in some cases): http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang.reflect/MethodgetAnnotationClassMyAnnoannotationClass.htm